# Jupyter ignores pyqtgraph class `_repr_png_`, but uses own classes' _repr_png_

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pyqtgraph

Dilemma: I'm extending pyqtgraph to be able to show inline plots. At the core, that should mean adding a `_repr_png_` method should suffice:

```
class PlotWindow(PlotWidget):
…
    def _repr_png_(self):
        exp = ImageExporter(self.plotItem)
        qimg = exp.export(toBytes=True)
        qbytearray = Qt.QByteArray()
        buffer = Qt.QBuffer(qbytearray)
        buffer.open(Qt.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        qimg.save(buffer, 'PNG')
        buffer.close()
        return bytes(buffer.data())
```

In practice, when I try to

```
%gui qt4
```

---

```
import PyQt4
import pyqtgraph
pw = pyqtgraph.plot(range(100))
pw.show()
```

---

```
pw
```

---

I would expect the Jupyter notebook to call the `_repr_png_` method. Instead, I get plain

```
<pyqtgraph.graphicsWindows.PlotWindow at 0x7f5f43666708>
```

Now, if I add a thin wrapper (`pw.show()` has been called before this):

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, pw):
        self._pw = pw
    def _repr_png_(self):
        return self._pw._repr_png_()
myobj = myclass(pw)
myobj
```

I get an inline plot, as expected. So, what am I doing wrong here? Why isn't the method used?

Comment: In the `myclass` example, did you also call `pw.show` before that?

Comment: @aaron yes, I did (thanks for pointing out that lack of clarity; edited)

Comment: close it :) `qimg`

Comment: @RaminNietzsche actually that makes no difference: The `_repr_png_` method simply is *never* called, so why should it matter whether the window is still open or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `PlotWidget.__getattr__()` erroneously raises a `NameError` instead of `AttributeError` when it is asked for a bad attribute. This trips up some extra checks that happen inside `IPython.utils.dir2.get_real_method()`, causing the method to be ignored.

If you fix `PlotWidget.__getattr__()` to raise `AttributeError` instead, then everything works as expected.

Comment: Excellent! Had to fix a couple of things on the way (including pseudo-staticality of the Parameter objects), but now it works. In 3h, I can assign my bounty to you. In the meantime, I'll wrap this up in a patch.